# How flip video capture from webcam in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, video, webcam

I noticed that when I am doing video capture from webcam in Silverlight video is "reversed" meaning when I am moving right then me on a screen moving left. Is there any way to flip video capture?

Comment: Cameras right or your right?

Comment: Cameras right. Basically it should be the same as looking at the mirror but its opposite right now

Comment: I think from what I remember you need to draw the image in reverse. Been a long time since I looked at silverlight

Comment: Do you how that can be done?

Comment: This looks promising  - [Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2010/09/07/silverlight-visual-effects-e-g-drop-shadow-blur-and-mirror-images.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I flipped a rectangle by opening project in Blend, selected my rectangle -> properties -> transformation -> flip by Y. How I didn't see it before...(sad trombone)

Answer (score 0):

I could flip left right and this is how you can do it.

```
private WriteableBitmap flipVideo(WriteableBitmap notFliped)
    {
        WriteableBitmap motionBmp = new WriteableBitmap(notFliped.PixelWidth, notFliped.PixelHeight);
        int leftRight = -1;
        int[] flipedArray = motionBmp.Pixels;
        int[] currentArray = notFliped.Pixels;
        for (int h = 0; h < 480; h++)
        {
            leftRight++;
            for (int w = 0; w < 640; w++)
            {
                flipedArray[h * 640 + w] = currentArray[639 + (h * 640) - w];
            }
        }
        return motionBmp;
    }
```

note that 640 and 480 are the camera resolutions and adjust them to your values. I don't know if webcam default support any other resolution. But If 640*480 then you can use this code as it is. Also you need to understand that even if the one cam frame looks like this in pixels ((3x3) picture)

0,1,2......................................................................................
3,4,5......................................................................................
6,7,8......................................................................................

bitmap.Pixels return []={0,1,2,3..8}
so you need to flip the values row by row into this

2,1,0......................................................................................
5,4,3......................................................................................
8,7,6......................................................................................

this is what the above code does..
cheers..and just ignore the dots...

Comment: Thanks for an effort but I found a much easier solution below:)

Comment: this is what you can do if you only using Silverlight, I answered your silverlight question..